# Wrong order after calling function

Tags: batch-file

I've written a small batch test script:

```
echo start
call:errorcheck "test"
echo main
goto exit

:errorcheck
echo errorcheck: %1
goto exit

:exit
echo end
```

The output:

```
start
errorcheck: "test"
end
main
end
```

I want to call the function errorcheck and then goto exit without entering the "main" part. But the script jumps back to the "main" section. Whats wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `call` then? the purpose of `call` is to return to the caller. Use `goto` to jump somewhere without returning; `goto` does not accept parameters like `call` though; so state `call:errorcheck "test" & got :exit` alternatively...? By the way: do not use `exit` as a label name as there is an internal command with that name; use something different, for instance, `end` or `quit`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a subfunction, it will always return.

The usual syntax to end a subfunction is `goto :eof`, which is implicit at the end of the script (after your `echo end`). Even a `exit 0` will return to the calling code.

You'd need to check for some condition and then end your program (eg. with an `exit`or `goto :eof`) after the `call` in your main code to avoid the second "end" output.

eg:

```
echo start
call:errorcheck "test"
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
echo main
goto exit

:errorcheck
echo errorcheck: %1
if <some error condition> exit 1
exit 0

:exit
echo end
```